# Detecting Which users are actively in a certain order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, web-applications

We have a LAMP based web portal where users create and access "orders". Orders contain several webpages full of different types of data, files etc.

What we would like to do is be able to tell what users are in the same order.

I.E. If Johnny goes into an order, and Susie and Jim are also in the order, we would have a small note on the page show who else is looking at that same order.

I thought about doing this by just keeping a table of users and orders they have accessed. Add to that table when they enter and order, remove from table when they leave, however, that does not account for the user closing the tab/browser. For this reason I also don't think any javascript/ajax solutions would work well.

This needs to be accurate to pretty much within a few seconds.

Could someone give me a brief overview of how this might be do-able (without using NodeJS)

Comment: I don't see how this could be done this way with just browsers.  You could implement a checkin/checkout system, though.  Of course, this requires users to check an order back in before they close the browser before anyone else could check out that order.

Answer (score 0):

"Accurate to within a few seconds" without some kind of AJAX solution is simply not going to happen. That's the stateless web for ya.

But, you can store, in a table, the following information.

```
 orderid    user     visit_time
```

Then, you can display the other visitors to each order most recent first. You can also eliminate the ones that are more than a particular age.  That will, most likely, meet your user interface goals.

Comment: Not trying to knock your solution, but how would this show who is actively in a particular order or if someone closes their browser to go to lunch, for example?

Comment: AJAX soultion would be fine, but what ajax solution would account for closing tab/browser?

Comment: There is no solution, AJAX or not, that can account for the browser abandoning the session. Your web app just doesn't hear from that user again. You must have a timeout on the recent visits list to deal with abandonment.

Comment: @OllieJones I thought about doing a 1 minute timeout (we could live with that) on the server side. Have the browser ping the server via ajax every 45 seconds or something. Then have a cron on the server side clearing out any that havent been updated in a minute or more. My concern there though is inactive tabs, the AJAX wouldn't send the message if the tab isn't actively being touched by the user, correct?

Comment: If the page is loaded javascript timed events will work. Don't bother with a high-frequency cron job. Just use `WHERE visit_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND` or something like that when looking up visitors to the page in question.  Once in a while (daily probably is OK) you can delete the old rows. If it's mission critical to never get this wrong -- to never identify a person who has already left the page -- web technology is not suitable.